# Shared passwords

Tags: password

I am looking for a password program that I can use with my partner. We have to create a lot of shared passwords, and it is difficult to do that with conventional programs like keepassx or password safe. Anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at https://github.com/KenKundert/password. It is a password generator rather than a password safe. The password is generated from a master password and the account name, so as long as you share the master password you can both generate the same password for an account. The program supports multiple master passwords, so you can have one you use for your personal passwords, and others that you share with your various partners. Underlying encryption is provided by gpg and it seems very secure. It also seems quite flexible. It comes with a scripting interface and will autotype usernames and passwords into a window based on the window title.

I have used it for a while, and I love it, but there is no GUI, so it demands a relatively sophisticated user.

-Avery